# React Native Expo cannot find type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I am using React Native with Expo framework with Typescript and my tsconfig.json have an include declaration with the path to the file with type declarations for images

```
//images.d.ts
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.jpeg";
declare module "*.svg";
declare module "*.gif";
declare module "*.png";
```

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "include": ["assets/*", "components/*", "types/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

```
//App.tsx
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import { HealthCheckForm } from "./components";
import hero from "./assets/hero-health-check.png";

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Image source={hero} style={styles.hero} />
        <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Health Check App</Text>
        <HealthCheckForm />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-start",
  },
  wrapper: {
    backgroundColor: "#75caee",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    maxWidth: 625,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  hero: {
    height: "50%",
    width: "100%",
  },
  welcomeText: {
    fontSize: 32,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});
```

In my other React Typescript projects, it was sufficient to point tsconfig.json to the type declarations, tell me please what I am missing. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe static images work with the `import` statement. Instead you need to use `require` [as per the docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/react-native/image/). They still comes in as `any` though, which is less than ideal.

Comment: thanks @AlexWayne it works, static import did work as well actually it's just that typescript was unhappy